# Azure Pipeline Checkout Task: How to exclude files under one folder named "analytics"

Tags: azure-devops

Currently I have one Azure DevOps pipeline (TelemetryCI.yml) as below, I try to exclude files under one folder names "analytics", how to update below checkout task?

```
steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: true
      fetchDepth: 1
      fetchTags: false
```

I reviewed Micrsoft doc for checkout task :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines

No any finding for exclude one folder files.

Answer (score -2):

As a workaround or Git repo practice, why not using `exclude` file in the `.git/info/` folder to lets Git know which untracked files to ignore and uses the same file search pattern syntax as a `.gitignore` file, you can refer at [Ignore file changes with Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/ignore-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2022#use-an-exclude-file)